# Invalid override copyWith

Tags: dart, extends

I've been wondering are there a best way to implement copyWith in extends?
got error in Pwm class copyWith method
how to fix dat?

**This Pin Code**

```
class Pin{

  final String? name;
  final int io;
  final bool value;
  final Mode mode;
  final Usage? usage;
  const Pin({required this.io,required this.value, required this.mode, this.name, this.usage});

  factory Pin.fromList(List<dynamic> list){
    // "pin1" : (33,hardwareR4A.pin1.value(),"IN" if hardwareR4A.pin1.init() == Pin.IN else "OUT"),
    return Pin(io: list[0], value: convertValueToBool(list[1]), mode: Mode.values.firstWhere((element) => element.name == list[2]), usage: null);
  }

  Pin copyWith(
    String? name,
    int io,
    bool value,
    Mode mode,
    Usage? usage,
  ){
    return Pin(
      io: io,
      mode: mode,
      value: value,
      name: name,
      usage: usage
    );
  }

}
```

**And this error class **

```
class Pwm extends Pin {

  final int frequency;
  final int duty;
  final int resolution;

  const Pwm({
    required super.io,
    required super.value,
    required super.mode,
    super.name,
    super.usage,
    required this.frequency,
    required this.duty,
    required this.resolution,
  }) : super();

  @override
  Pwm copyWith({
    String? name,
    int? io,
    bool? value,
    Mode? mode,
    Usage? usage,
    int? frequency,
    int? duty,
    int? resolution,
  }) {
    return Pwm(
      duty: duty ?? this.duty,
      frequency: frequency ?? this.frequency,
      io: io ?? this.io,
      mode: mode ?? this.mode,
      resolution: resolution ?? this.resolution,
      value: value ?? this.value,
      name: name ?? this.name,
      usage: usage ?? this.usage,
    );
  }
}
```

Are there a best way to implement copyWith in extends?
do i need to extends pin with abstraction?
like :

class Controller{

}

class Pin extends Controller{}

class Pwm extends Controller{}
E32 mean esp32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(In the future, please copy-and-paste the error message that you received.)

Your problem is that `Pin.copyWith` takes only [*positional* parameters](https://dart.dev/language/functions#parameters):

> ```dart
>  Pin copyWith(
>    String? name,
>    int io,
>    bool value,
>    Mode mode,
>    Usage? usage,
>  ){
> ```

but the `Pwm.copyWith` override takes only [*named* parameters](https://dart.dev/language/functions#named-parameters):

> ```dart
>  @override
>  Pwm copyWith({
>    String? name,
>    int? io,
>    bool? value,
>    Mode? mode,
>    Usage? usage,
>    int? frequency,
>    int? duty,
>    int? resolution,
>  }) {
> ```

An override's signature must be *compatible* with the base method's; that is, it must be callable using the base method's signature (e.g. `pwm.copyWith(name, io, value, mode, usage)`).

You can fix it either by:

- Changing `Pin.copyWith` to use optional, named parameters.
- Changing `Pwm.copyWith` to use positional parameters for the parameters it shares.